# Pandas: Group by, filter rows, get the mean

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by, mean

In python I have a pandas data frame `df` like this:

```
 ID      Geo    Speed
123    False       40
123     True       90
123     True       80
123    False       50
123     True       10
456    False       10
456     True       90
456    False       40
456     True       80
```

I want to group `df` by `ID`, and filter out rows where `Geo == False`, and get the mean of `Speed` in the group. So the result should look like this.

```
 ID     Mean 
123       60  
456       85
```

My attempt:

```
df.groupby('ID')["Geo" == False].Speed.mean()
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda g: g.Geo == False)
df[df.Geo.groupby(df.ID) == False]
```

Neither of them worked. 
Any solutions? Thank you!

Comment: ````df[df["Geo"] == False].groupby('ID')['Speed'].mean()````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `~` for inverting `False`s to `True`s for filtering by `False`s by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[~df["Geo"]])
    ID    Geo  Speed
0  123  False     40
3  123  False     50
5  456  False     10
7  456  False     40

df = df[~df["Geo"]].groupby('ID', as_index=False).Speed.mean()
print (df)
    ID  Speed
0  123     45
1  456     25
```

And for filtering by `True`s:

```
print (df[df["Geo"]])
    ID   Geo  Speed
1  123  True     90
2  123  True     80
4  123  True     10
6  456  True     90
8  456  True     80

df = df[df["Geo"]].groupby('ID', as_index=False).Speed.mean()
print (df)
    ID  Speed
0  123     60
1  456     85
```

Comment: @GabrielMacotti - It is good idea only if possible another values as `True` and `False`s, if boolean only better is use `~`

Answer (score 2):

By using `pivot_table`, now you get Both True and False mean

```
df.pivot_table('Speed','ID','Geo',aggfunc='mean')
Out[154]: 
Geo  False  True 
ID               
123     45     60
456     25     85
```